# How to create a deeply nested object across multiple Views in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This is a question about site design in ASP.NET MVC. I have a object graph that goes three levels deep. Say there is a Container object that has multiple Boxes and each Box has multiple Capsules. The Boxes and Capsules have enough properties that each one should really have its own separate View. The issue here is when I am in a **Create** situation, how do I spread the views for these objects across multiple requests and still allow the user to persist the top level Container object in a single transaction? Note that the user is creating the Container and all its nested children in one operation and there are no IDs for anything at this point.

The user's experience should be: click a "Create Container" link, arrive at a page with all container fields and a (empty) list of Box names or ids with a "Add Box" link below. Clicking the Add box link should take the user to the Box detail page with Box level fields and a list of Capsule names/IDs, and Add Capsule link, and the process repeats itself.

The techniques that come to mind offhand are:

1. Implement it as a single page where we display the Box/Capsule entry form and save the data into hidden fields in the list named according to convention. In other words, emulate a separate detail page experience on the front end.
2. Use TempData or something to pass the parent object to the detail page for the child, and back again when user is done with entering the child data.

Neither of these look like particularly good options to me and I am sure there is something basic here that I am just missing. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If possible, look at it a different way: do the minimum to allow the user to setup the container and persist it. Flag it as "incomplete" if needed. Then allow children to be added to the container (using its ID), persisting frequently and automatically. A single page works well for this (smooth user experience), but it isn't required. That way, you avoid having to  manage a bunch of unpersisted state, and also avoid the user losing work because they had to set the whole thing up before it could be saved.

Comment: If that isn't possible, you could use the one page approach. If you want to use multiple pages, then you will probably need Session (TempData is Session-based, but it is consumed when it is accessed once). The usual caveats about Session apply, but it is definitely suitable for this purpose if there is no other alternative.

Comment: Wouldn't partial views handle this?  The top level view would be for the container, and would accept a container model.  The page then renders partial views for the box / capsule, passing in the box/capsule model into their respective views.  With a little bit of javascript, you'd be able to do this all on a single page and commit the entire object in a single POST.

Comment: @BrendanGreen - partial views + single page + JS would be the crux of a good solution. There will be some work required to dynamically add new items (a new partial must be obtained from the server or created on the client). Model binding on the controller may also need customization to handle an object tree more than 2 levels deep.